# Is there a standard formatting function or operator that will round up? (or down?)

Tags: c++, formatting, number-formatting, ostringstream

I am using ostringstream to output a number to 2 decimal places as follows

```
std::ostringstream ostr;

ostr << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2);
ostr << cylinderLength;
```

So, if cylinderLength = 0.594, the above outputs 0.59 as expected.

Is there an operator or function that will round up or down in the last desired decimal place?

In this case, the above example would print out 0.60 instead.

Comment: You need [ceil()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/ceil/)

Comment: @AlokSave it becomes 1 if use ceil in my testing

Comment: So you want to round up or down at a specific number of decimal places?

Comment: Yes, I thought of ceil, but that is defined as "returns the smallest integral value that is not less than x". I want the rounding to be applied in the last desired decimal place.

Comment: @AndrewS.: Check Loki's edit to the answer.

Comment: @Troy Yes, exactly. So 0.594 becomes 0.60 (using 2 decimal places)

Comment: I see, nice manipulation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
// Round towards +infinity (to 1 decimal place (use 100 for 2 decimal places)
ceil(double * 10) / 10


// Round towards -infinity (to 1 decimal place (use 100 for 2 decimal places)
floor(double * 10) / 10
```

Comment: Yes, this clearly works - thank you. But there is no function or method that does this directly? I want to experiment with different precisions of rounding so this is a bit ungainly.

Comment: @AndrewS. You can write a wrapper which does this.